# Python/Selenium Stale Element Reference in For Loop

Tags: python, loops, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, staleelementreferenceexception

I'm having trouble looping through a list of company ID's and using them in a search bar. My code works just fine when the text file contains just one ID, but when I add a second ID to the list it won't even perform the last click for the first ID, let alone search for the second one, and then gives me a stale element reference exception. This is driving me insane so any help would be amazing. I'm not very experienced at all so bear with me if I don't understand a request for more information or your solution.

Code:

```
company_list = open('Company_List.txt')
for line in company_list:
  company_id = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SearchTopBar"]')
  company_id.send_keys(line)
  company_id.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
  driver.implicitly_wait(10)
  driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="CompanyHeaderInfo_TearSheetReport_ReportImage"]/div/img').click()
  driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

Traceback:

```
File "<ipython-input-5-3766dfd38c2f>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('C:/Users/kdixon/Desktop/Business_Intelligence/PROJECTS/Scripts/Pull Tearsheets.py', wdir='C:/Users/kdixon/Desktop/Business_Intelligence/PROJECTS/Scripts')

File "C:\Users\kdixon\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\kdixon\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/kdixon/Desktop/Business_Intelligence/PROJECTS/Scripts/Pull Tearsheets.py", line 42, in <module>
company_id.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

File "C:\Users\kdixon\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 479, in send_keys
'value': keys_to_typing(value)})

File "C:\Users\kdixon\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 628, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)

File "C:\Users\kdixon\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 314, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)

File "C:\Users\kdixon\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

(Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.99)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the traceback, particularly the fact that the exception is thrown from the line `company_id.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)` and the type of the exception, it appears that the search box (with id `SearchTopBar`) is replaced with another element when you start typing.

I guess that if you'll send the Enter press *together* with the value, it will solve the problem. I.e.:

```
company_id.send_keys(line + Keys.ENTER)
```

In case it doesn't, open the Developer Tools in the browser and see which element replaces the `SearchTopBar` element when you start typing. In the code, after sending the `line` keystrokes to the `company_id` element, search for the element that you found to replaces it, and send the Enter keypress to that element instead of to the `company_id`.

Comment: YES! That was it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

company_id = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='SearchTopBar']"))
)
```

it will wait until element will be present in DOM

Full code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

company_list = open('Company_List.txt')
for line in company_list:
  company_id = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='SearchTopBar']")))
  company_id.send_keys(line)
  company_id.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
  driver.implicitly_wait(10)
  driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="CompanyHeaderInfo_TearSheetReport_ReportImage"]/div/img').click()
  driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

Comment: I've clicked through a lot of pages and inspected the search bar and it always has the same xpath, is that the wrong way to check for a new xpath or does that mean it is something else?

Comment: When you find this element via xPath in browser dev tools on the second iteration, do you getting this element still highlighted?

Comment: Yes it's still highlighted. When highlighted it says: input#SearchTopBar.cSearchBoxDisabled

It also says that on the first iteration as well.

Comment: Try to debug your code and check if on the second iteration your `line` is not `None`